# Does refrigerating (but not freezing) bread inhibit mycelium growth?

Tags: food, mycology

During COVID, supermarkets struggled to keep things in stock. Bread seemed to be hard to come by for a time. As a result, when I came across the brand I liked, I grabbed a couple extra loaves. I didn't want the extra to go bad, so at first I froze it, but that was harsh on the bread. However, it turned out that simply refrigerating it was amazing! It seems to last indefinitely, although it eventually hardens if left for too long (around a month?). I thought I had found a cool trick, as it takes us a while to go through a loaf of bread.

The other day I watched [a YouTube video about mold growth and food safety](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgduUAu8s3g). From [3:06](https://youtu.be/NgduUAu8s3g?t=185) to 4:13 in the video, he explains that before bread has visible spores, there are already mycelia in the bread. In other words the bread is already moldy before mold is visible.

I began to wonder: is refrigeration actually preventing mycelium growth, or is it only preventing spores? I noticed a commenter on the video raise the same question.

In case it's relevant: Two meat thermometers sitting on the shelf where I keep my bread read 40 degrees F, as does an IR thermometer pointed at the bread bag. According to a quick Google search, that seems to be an acceptable refrigerator temperature.

Comment: Welcome calcmari. This is not simply a Q&A site, here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on, see our section on [how to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). There are some things you should investigate: (Cont...)

Comment: (Cont) Common bread-mould growth temperatures? What bread? What does the ingredient list say about: ascorbic acid, sulphur dioxide, sulphites, calcium/sodium propionate, ginger, garlic, clove, cinnamon? Does your jurisdiction even require these things to be disclosed on the label?  Or is is fresh from the baker's oven without preservatives? Then you can [edit] your question to include your research in attempting to answer the question and where you got stuck.